# How could I estimate my memory device access speed?

Tags: memory, hardware

My memory is DDR2 800MHz

```
dmidecode -t memory

Handle 0x1100, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1000
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM_1
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
    Manufacturer: 7F98000000000000
    Serial Number: 2DCCDD00
    Asset Tag: 050916
    Part Number:
```

I want to estimate the write or read speed by this info.

Is 800MHz means read/write 800bits per second?

Should we multiple 64 bit datawidth? eg: 800*64 bits/sec. So we can read/write 800*64/8 bytes/sec?

Thanks advance!

Comment: I suggest getting the datasheet for the memories in question and a good reference on how [S|D]DRAM works.   Even then you will only get an upper bound on bandwidth.    Note that in DDR, both edges of the clock are used to transfer data.

Comment: @Marko Thanks! good propose.

Comment: Mhz is million per second, not per second, so 800Mhz means 800 million operations/sec